# When its necessary to add backslash before dot when using sed

Tags: sed, regular-expression

We need to replace the server_`mn.ftg.com` with localhost in file `ambari-agent.ini` as the following

```
echo $machine
server_mn

echo $domain
ftg.com

more ambari-agent.ini
[server]
hostname=localhost
```

is it necessary to add backslash before the dot as the following:

```
sed "s/hostname=localhost/hostname=$machine\.$domain/g"  ambari-agent.ini
```

or it safe to do just ( without back slash )

```
sed "s/hostname=localhost/hostname=$machine.$domain/g"  ambari-agent.ini
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You only ever have to escape the dot if it is part of a regular expression and should match a literal dot.  To match a literal dot with a regular expression, you may use either `\.` or `[.]`.

The replacement part of an `s` expression in `sed` is however *not* a regular expression.

The only characters that need to be escaped there (with backslash) are `\`, `&`, newline, and the `s` command delimiter (`/` if using `s/pattern/replacement/`).

This means that your command

```
sed "s/hostname=localhost/hostname=$machine.$domain/g"  ambari-agent.ini
```

would work, as long as the values of the variables involved adhere to the above-mentioned rules. I would personally additionally anchor the expression to the start of the line and drop the `g` flag from the `s` command.